# Truecrypt encrypted system partition run with administrator privileges

Tags: truecrypt

First, some background :

I previously had an encrypted file container but now when I try to mount this via the same script, I get a warning that it is read only. I originally thought that this was a problem with the file, but when I manually run truecrypt as administrator, it is able to mount it correctly. I am running WIndows 7, 64-bit.

--

Now all that has changed is I have added full system partition encryption, so I guess that this causes TrueCrypt to run at startup, but without Administrator privileges.

--

My question is this: Is it likely that the cause of the problem is that TrueCrypt does not have the correct privileges when run at startup as opposed to when started by a script. And if so, is there a way to make this work??

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried checking the properties of the container and make sure that it's not flagged to read only?

Comment: The container remains the same. Not read only and I am the owner, with full permissions. If I start TrueCrypt manually using 'Run as Admin', it works fine.